# wordpress loop for specific category

Tags: loop

i have this snippet for specific category it works perfect
but i want little modification to show posts by Ascending order.

```
<?php

 // The Query
 query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'A', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

 // The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <li>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 </li>

 <?php endwhile;

 // Reset Query
 wp_reset_query();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure query_posts is the worst way to query...

Always use get_posts from what I'm constantly told.
Remove the arguments that you don't use on the array below.

```
$args  = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 5000,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'category'        => ,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'ASC',
    'include'         => ,
    'exclude'         => ,
    'meta_key'        => ,
    'meta_value'      => ,
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'  => ,
    'post_parent'     => ,
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true ); 
$posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post) :
    ?><div class="">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
          <?php 
               echo the_title();
               echo the_post_thumbnail(array(360,360));
               the_excerpt('more text');
          ?></a></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php
```

WP_query method with category id's:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => array( 2, 6 ), 'order' => 'ASC') );
```

Or change the query like this, but I don't know how to add ascending to it:

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type' );

    function add_my_custom_post_type( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() )
            $query->set( 'category', 'A' );
         // $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' ); maybe?
        return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 'order'=> 'ASC' to your query

```
 query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'A', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an argument to the array...

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'A', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

...but don't use query_posts, see [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) why. Instead you could do this:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'A',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$your_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($your_query->have_posts()) : $your_query->the_post();
```